# c# changing this line so it outputs the string as a variable

Tags: c#, linq, variables, postdata

UPDATE TO POST ORIGIANAL POST AFTER THIS CODE --- this code is an update to what david has been helping me do its throwing one error need help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost/test2.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["var1"] = formData["var1"] = string.Format("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);
        formData["var2"] = ip();


        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    public void ip()
    {
        String publicIP = "";

        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                publicIP = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        //Search for the ip in the html
        int first = publicIP.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = publicIP.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        publicIP = publicIP.Substring(first, last - first);

        Console.WriteLine(publicIP);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);


    }
}
}

this is the error I am getting 
Error   2 - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.ip()'
I am trying to create a function that will send the out put as var2
```

I have this c# script

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
}
```

how can I change this so it outputs the string to a variable say "VAR2" and use it in this script

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost/test2.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["var1"] = "THIS IS WHERE VAR2 NEEDS TO BE ";


        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
}
```

SO HOW CAN I ADD THE MACHINE NAME SCRIPT TO THIS FUNCTION AND THEN USE IT AS VAR2 
any help would be brilliant

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        String publicIP = "";

        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                publicIP = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        //Search for the ip in the html
        int first = publicIP.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = publicIP.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        publicIP = publicIP.Substring(first, last - first);

        Console.WriteLine(publicIP);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

her is the update david I would like to incude this script in my other script so it looks like this

```
formData["var1"] = formData["var1"] = string.Format("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);
formData["var2"] = "this is where this script needs to be  ";
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in a separate application?  Can't you just do: `formData["var1"] = string.Format("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);` ?

Comment: write that as my answer and I will tick it as that is the ifo I was looking for my script is now functional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it need to be in a separate application?  If one application's output is going to be the command-line argument for another application's input, then they're both running on the same machine.  Which means, in this case, they'd both get the same value from `System.Environment.MachineName`.

You can just get the value in the application where it's needed:

```
formData["var1"] = string.Format("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Comment: davind could u also help me intergrate another console application into another formdat var like last time

Comment: @user2847609: Well, if you have another question on Stack Overflow then I can perhaps take a look at that.

Comment: its to do with this question really ill add the other source code you can always add the answer to here again and ill tick it ill update my code now

Comment: it is updated I would love it if u can help me include this script into the othe console app I have in c# and output the result as the var2

Comment: @user2847609: Regarding your edit... It sounds like what you want to start doing is create functions for calculating your values.  So instead of a separate application which writes the result to the console, you can just create a separate function which returns the result.  Something like `private string CalculateSomeValue() { // code here }`  Then you'd call it with: `formData["var1"] = CalculateSomeValue();`

Comment: okay I am trying it now if you could show me an example of what your mean just add it as an edit to my post

Comment: I have tried doing as u say but it keeps chucking me erros out could u please help me do this so I can fully understand what you mean

Comment: david I have updated my code its throwing an error hope you can help I have tried fixing this myself I am a newbie and struggling lol

Comment: @user2847609: There's very little that can be done in the format of these comments.  But if you have specific code which is giving a specific error, I recommend asking a new question and demonstrating the code and the error.

Comment: okay david I am going to do I new question now I will give you a link here soon I think I nearly have it I just have a unhandled error now wich I am sure is retty simple

Comment: @user2847609: Thanks, hopefully I'll be able to help.  It's not that I don't want to be helpful, it's just that the format of Stack Overflow tries to avoid long comment threads in favor of straight-forward questions and answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214223/c-sharp-function-as-variable-throwing-error-notimplementedexception-unhandled heres my new qestion