# Function as variable throwing error NotImplementedException unhandled

Tags: c#, string, function, variables

okay so I have added a function to my c# script to fetch ip address and send the output as string in a variable heres my source

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost/test2.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["var1"] = formData["var1"] = string.Format("MachineName: {0}", System.Environment.MachineName);
        formData["var2"] = stringGetPublicIpAddress();
        formData["var3"] = "DGPASS";

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private static string stringGetPublicIpAddress()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
        private string GetPublicIpAddress()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ifconfig.me");

        request.UserAgent = "curl"; // this simulate curl linux command

        string publicIPAddress;

        request.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                publicIPAddress = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return publicIPAddress.Replace("\n", "");

    }
    }
    }
```

basically I have created this function

```
private static string stringGetPublicIpAddress()
```

and I am sending it as a variable

```
formdata["var2"] = stringGetPublicIpAddress();
```

I am getting this error

```
throw new NotImplementedException();  === NotImplementedException was unhandled
```

Comment: Are you kidding? What would you expect it to do with this single line: `throw new NotImplementedException();`?

Comment: Take a look at your `stringGetPublicIpAddress()` function...you might notice something...

Comment: no I am not kidding I am new to this coding and took me a while to get this far I know I need to change that notimplementedexceptions(); to some kind of code so this sends properly but being a noob I just don't know what

Comment: It's great that you fixed the issue. Please write up your fix in an answer, below - don't edit your question in the way you did, which invalidates the answers you got already.

Answer (score 0):

You... didn't implement the method.  You have this:

```
private static string stringGetPublicIpAddress()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So of course any time you call that method, it's going to throw that exception.  It looks like you *did* implement the method you want here, though:

```
private string GetPublicIpAddress()
{
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Maybe this is the result of some copy/paste error?  Try getting rid of the small method that throws the exception and changing the implemented method to be static:

```
private static string GetPublicIpAddress()
{
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Then update anywhere you call it from this:

```
stringGetPublicIpAddress();
```

to this:

```
GetPublicIpAddress();
```

This really just looks like copy/paste errors gone wrong in strange ways.  Or perhaps you're struggling with the difference between static and instance methods?  Maybe you implemented the method, but the compiler suggested that you needed a static method?  There's a lot to read about static vs. instance methods/members which I won't really get into here.  It's a significant concept in object-oriented programming.

In this particular case, since you're in the context of a static method in `Main`, anything you call from `Main` on that class (the `Program` class) also needs to be static, unless you create an *instance* of `Program` like this:

```
var program = new Program();
```

This would allow you to call instance methods on `Program`:

```
program.SomeNonStaticMethod();
```

But for a small application such as this, that isn't really necessary.

Comment: have a look at my other threads you will see I have been working on this for days

Comment: You should really pick up a book on C#/programming. Your questions are gigantic "how can I do xxx huge task" questions. This one was staring you straight in the face. A book would definitely help.